# cambiar el action de un formulario dependiendo del valor de un input

Tags: javascript, html

este es mi form:

```
<form action="" id="comprobante" class="frm-ventas" method="post">
  <input type="text"  name="nombre" id="nombre">
  <input type="hidden"  name="cod" id="cod" value="">
  <button type="submit">
</form>
```

Necesito que cuando el valor del input "cod" sea 01 me envíe al action="ventas/registrar_venta" o si es 03 me envíe a action="ventas/registrar_compra". ¿Es posible hacer eso? ¿Cómo sería?

Comment: Hola Fernando, tiene algo hecho? si es asi compartenos el codigo para poder ayudarte. Si no, intenta resolverlo tu mismo, y si te traba con algo o surge algun error, nos peeguntas.

Comment: @Fernando Abel Gonzales Ch Bienvenido te invito a leer [ask] para que recibas excelentes respuestas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  if(document.getElementById('cod').value == '01')
    formulario.setAttribute('action', 'ventas/registrar_venta')

  if(document.getElementById('cod').value == '03')
    formulario.setAttribute('action', 'ventas/registrar_compra')

  document.getElementById('comprobante').submit()

})
```

```html
<form action="#" id="comprobante" class="frm-ventas" method="post">
  <input type="text"  name="nombre" id="nombre">
  <input type="hidden"  name="cod" id="cod" value="">
  <button type="submit" id="send">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

> **Recuerda** que con Javascript todo es posible

Comment: muchas gracias amigo

Comment: me surgio otro problema D: al enviar el formulario ahora se queda en ahi y me muestra el mensaje {"respuesta":true,"mensaje":{},"codigo":""} pero no deberia quedarse ahi ya que ventas/registrar_ventas es una clase no deberia salir de la pagina donde se genera el form

Comment: No entiendo bien, ¿no envía el formulario o es otro problema?

Comment: ya lo solucione amigo gracias