# Cambiar Tag "Action" mediante variable

Tags: javascript, html, mvc

Me gustaría saber si es posible cambiar el tag de un "Action" mediante una variable. Por poner un ejemplo:

```
<form method="Post" action="/Lineas/Create">
```

Me gustaría que la accíon "Create" cambiara en función del botón al que le doy, es decir:

```
<form method="Post" action="/Lineas/selected_action">
```

donde "selected_action" pudiera ser: [Create, Delete, Update... etc] en función del botón pulsado.

Por el momento no he intentado nada ya que ni siquiera estoy seguro de que eso se pueda hacer.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Sí, se puede hacer. El **action** de los **form** es un atributo. Podrías modificarlo por medio de la función **attr()** de Jquery al igual que harías con el **name**, por ejemplo.

Comment: La respuesta es **si**. Y podrías hacer algo parecido a [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137139/cambiar-el-action-de-un-formulario-dependiendo-del-valor-de-un-input). Sin embargo yo suelo hacerlo directamente con un evento `onclick()` en cada botón

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Me pongo a ello, un saludo!! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos puedes hacerlo así:

```js
  function cambiarAction(accion){
   //obtengo el formulario
    formulario = document.getElementById('miForm');
    //valido boton Crear
    if(accion == 'create')
     //defino el action
     formulario.setAttribute('action','miurl_create');
      //valido boton Actualizar
    if(accion == 'update')
     //defino el action
     formulario.setAttribute('action','miurl_update');
      //valido boton Otro
    if(accion == 'otro')
     //defino el action
     formulario.setAttribute('action','miurl_otro');
    
  }//end function cambiarAction
```

```html
<form action="" id="miForm">
  <input type="text" name="test" id="test">
  <input type="submit" value="Aceptar">
</form>
<br>
<button onclick="cambiarAction('create');">Crear</button><br>
<button onclick="cambiarAction('update');">Actualizar</button><br>
<button onclick="cambiarAction('otro');">Otro</button>
```

Como notaras dentro del **button** existe el evento **onclick**  el cual manda a llamar una funcion "cambiarAction" la misma recibe como parametro el evento deseado para controlarlo y definir el url de action, su vez el formulario lo obtengo mediante el respectivo **ID**.

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

Una manera facil es definir tus acciones en los botones:

```
    <form name="form">

      <!-- controles-->

      <input type="submit" value="Crear" onclick="javascript: form.action='/Create';">

      <input type="submit" value="Borrar" onclick="javascript: form.action='/Delete';"> 
      <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" onclick="javascript: form.action='/Update';"> 

</form>
```